# Why assigning to a builtin type rvalue is not legal

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, lvalue

Given the following code:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

void Dummy0(std::array<unsigned, 10>& an_array) { --std::end(an_array); }
void Dummy1(std::vector<unsigned>& a_vector) { --std::end(a_vector); }
```

From the point of view of the "standards makers", how do you justify the fact that `Dummy0` produces `error: expression is not assignable`. One return value is a raw pointer, the other a class. Why this double standard (no pun intended)?

I bet there is a lot of broken template code because of this fact. People don't always use `std::advance()`.

Codes:

[C and C++ exemples](https://godbolt.org/z/nP35fPdM4)

Comment: built in types and class types have different semantics.  `--std::end(a_vector);` is actually `end_iterator.operator--()`, whereas `--std::end(an_array);` is actually `--rvalue_end_pointer` which doesn't work because you have an rvalue.

Comment: Unrelated usage note: Deleting the previous question only to re-ask it with a better title a few minutes later may have been a mis-step. Deleted questions weigh against you when the server computes how often you can ask questions. Doesn't look like you're close to earning a restriction, but I have no clue how many deleted almost- good questions you might have lurking under the water. It is in your interests to fix questions.

Comment: The really interesting part of the question is it compiles with the `std::vector`, but not with the `std::array` and the question brings this up, but it should be highlighting this detail.

Comment: And you can't just transform `--rvalue` into `rvalue-1` because then you take a dependency on random-access iteration, while currently you just need bidi

Comment: I don't see `DummyA` anywhere in your code. Do you mean `Dummy0`?

Comment: Still, a shorter rewrite than invoking `std::advance` is `auto it = rvalue; return --it;`

Comment: @user4581301 The answer to your musings is simply that nothing prevents an iterator implementation from being a superset of the iterator's requirements. This makes such inconsistencies not necessarily unexpected. However, IMO, it should behoove any good standard library implementation to use as tight as possible implementations.

Comment: _"People don't always use `std::advance()`."_ yes of course. But 99.9999...% of those people also don't use `--std:end(...)`. Else they would have had an issue. And yes, there's a lot of broken code out there. For various reasons.

Comment: @user4581301 It's not about why it produces an error, that I understand. The question is why it should produce an error, that creates inconsistencies in the way code looks and for such a simple case, I feels awful.